# phpwebsocket not working

Tags: php, javascript, shell, websocket, phpwebsocket

This is the tutorial I used:

http://www.flynsarmy.com/2012/02/php-websocket-chat-application-2-0/comment-page-1/#comments

Basically I downloaded the source code, placed the files in a folder: http://mmhudson.com/ws

server.php:
http://mmhudson.com/ws/server.php

I simply can't get it to connect. I tried running server.php from both the command line and the browser and both times it wouldn't connect. The ws folder has all the files in the downloadable source included.

Any ideas of what I can try?

Comment: Have you tried different ports? A guy in the comments changed to 8080 and got it working.

Comment: how would i change the port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the solution. You are opening a connection to `localhost/127.0.0.1`. As soon as you put the code on a server, you'll have to specify the server URL instead of `localhost/127.0.0.1` for the client. I tested the server.php and it is working fine, only the client doesn't connect to it.

Try this for index.html

```
Server = new FancyWebSocket('ws://mmhudson.com:9300');
```

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately. Appears to work the same as it did before.

Comment: Does your Provider allow Socket connections on PHP? Only few providers do. I tried the Example on local xampp installation and it's working Great

Comment: it's not working on my local xampp installation. What steps did you follow?

Comment: 1 - start the server (e.g. `php -q server.php`) and choose a port that is currently unused ... 2 - open the index.html in an editor and choose the same port as for the server .... 3 - open the index.html in a browser

Comment: And check `phpinfo` for the `socket` setting

Comment: what is the socket setting called? and how do i choose a port/set it?

Comment: got this error: Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. )

Comment: You set the port inside the server.php and index.html ... both the same of course. And you use a Browser that supports websockets

Comment: Damn, you saved me. Been looking for this for weeks. Not the solution, but you contributed for my work! Finally got a websockets example working.